# How do I use twilio to send SMS in Expo React Native?

Tags: react-native, twilio, expo

I tried to integrate the Twilio node module in my expo project but it failed with the following error message:

```
The package at "node_modules/twilio/lib/webhooks/webhooks.js" attempted to import the Node standard library module "crypto". It failed because React Native does not include the Node standard library
```

Has anyone integrated twilio in an Expo Project ? Is there another module that works for expo ? Any other possible solution ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your architecture is a little incorrect, you need to do this service in the backend, if you wanna do it with NodeJS, you'll probably use along with [Express](https://expressjs.com). Just check in the [Twilio docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/quickstart/node).